# Count distinct words from a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, text, pandas

I've a Pandas data frame, where one column contains text. I'd like to get a list of unique words appearing across the entire column (space being the only split).

```
import pandas as pd

r1=['My nickname is ft.jgt','Someone is going to my place']

df=pd.DataFrame(r1,columns=['text'])
```

The output should look like this:

```
['my','nickname','is','ft.jgt','someone','going','to','place']
```

It wouldn't hurt to get a count as well, but it is not required.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use a `set` to create the sequence of unique elements.

Do some clean-up on `df` to get the strings in lower case and split:

```
df['text'].str.lower().str.split()
Out[43]: 
0             [my, nickname, is, ft.jgt]
1    [someone, is, going, to, my, place]
```

Each list in this column can be passed to `set.update` function to get unique values. Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to do so:

```
results = set()
df['text'].str.lower().str.split().apply(results.update)
print(results)

set(['someone', 'ft.jgt', 'my', 'is', 'to', 'going', 'place', 'nickname'])
```

Or use with `Counter()` from comments:

```
from collections import Counter
results = Counter()
df['text'].str.lower().str.split().apply(results.update)
print(results)
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. And if you want to keep count, you could use `results = Counter()`.

Comment: This is Beautiful!

Comment: Awesome the solution with Counter ! :)

Comment: Awesome solution, scales much better than other solutions

Comment: This uses a very high amount of RAM. Flip it like this to use much less RAM: `df['text'].apply(lambda x: results.update(x.split()))`

Answer (score 27):

If you want to do it from the DataFrame construct:

```
import pandas as pd

r1=['My nickname is ft.jgt','Someone is going to my place']

df=pd.DataFrame(r1,columns=['text'])

df.text.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.split(" "))).sum(axis = 0)

My          1
Someone     1
ft.jgt      1
going       1
is          2
my          1
nickname    1
place       1
to          1
dtype: float64
```

If you want a more flexible tokenization use `nltk` and its `tokenize`

Comment: Kudos for adressing the *whole* problem of the question: `DataFrame` and `count`

Comment: Really slow on my dataframe (n = 90,000)

Answer (score 25):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> r1=['My nickname is ft.jgt','Someone is going to my place']
>>> Counter(" ".join(r1).split(" ")).items()
[('Someone', 1), ('ft.jgt', 1), ('My', 1), ('is', 2), ('to', 1), ('going', 1), ('place', 1), ('my', 1), ('nickname', 1)]
```

Answer (score 11):

Building on @Ofir Israel's answer, specific to Pandas:

```
from collections import Counter
result = Counter(" ".join(df['text'].values.tolist()).split(" ")).items()
result
```

Will give you what you want, this converts the text column series values to a list, splits on spaces and counts the instances.

Answer (score 5):

```
uniqueWords = list(set(" ".join(r1).lower().split(" ")))
count = len(uniqueWords)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the discussion, here are the timings for three of the proposed solutions (skipping conversion to list) on a 92816 row dataframe:

```
from collections import Counter
results = set()

%timeit -n 10 set(" ".join(df['description'].values.tolist()).lower().split(" "))
```

323 ms ± 4.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit -n 10 df['description'].str.lower().str.split(" ").apply(results.update)
```

316 ms ± 4.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit -n 10 Counter(" ".join(df['description'].str.lower().values.tolist()).split(" "))
```

365 ms ± 2.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
len(list(set(" ".join(df['description'].values.tolist()).lower().split(" "))))
```

13561

```
len(results)
```

13561

```
len(Counter(" ".join(df['description'].str.lower().values.tolist()).split(" ")).items())
```

13561

I tried the Pandas only approach too but it took way longer and used > 25GB of RAM making my 32GB laptop swap.

All others are pretty fast. I would use solution 1 for being a one liner, or 3 if word counts are needed.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Use `collections.Counter` to get the counts of unique words in column in dataframe (without stopwords)

Given:

```
$ cat test.csv 
Description
crazy mind california medical service data base...
california licensed producer recreational & medic...
silicon valley data clients live beyond status...
mycrazynotes inc. announces $144.6 million expans...
leading provider sustainable energy company prod ...
livefreecompany founded 2005, listed new york stock...
```

Code:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

import pandas as pd

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import word_tokenize

stoplist = set(stopwords.words('english') + list(punctuation))

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep='\t')

texts = df['Description'].str.lower()

word_counts = Counter(word_tokenize('\n'.join(texts)))

word_count.most_common()
```

[out]:

```
[('...', 6), ('california', 2), ('data', 2), ('crazy', 1), ('mind', 1), ('medical', 1), ('service', 1), ('base', 1), ('licensed', 1), ('producer', 1), ('recreational', 1), ('&', 1), ('medic', 1), ('silicon', 1), ('valley', 1), ('clients', 1), ('live', 1), ('beyond', 1), ('status', 1), ('mycrazynotes', 1), ('inc.', 1), ('announces', 1), ('$', 1), ('144.6', 1), ('million', 1), ('expans', 1), ('leading', 1), ('provider', 1), ('sustainable', 1), ('energy', 1), ('company', 1), ('prod', 1), ('livefreecompany', 1), ('founded', 1), ('2005', 1), (',', 1), ('listed', 1), ('new', 1), ('york', 1), ('stock', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this method here which is pure pandas and makes use of [pd.DataFrame.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). Explode turns each element of a list into a row that shares an ID with the original row.

```py
# Get all unique words
df['text'].str.split().explode().unique()

# Get all unique words with frequency counts
df['text'].str.split().explode().value_counts()
```

```py
r1 = ['My nickname is ft.jgt','Someone is going to my place']

df = pd.DataFrame(r1,columns=['text'])
df['text'].str.split().explode().value_counts()
>>>
text
is          2
My          1
nickname    1
ft.jgt      1
Someone     1
going       1
to          1
my          1
place       1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

print unique list of words

```py
new_list=list(set(df['text'].str.lower().str.split().sum()))
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score -4):

If Dataframe has ' a',  'b', 'c' etc, column And to count distinct words of each column then
You could use,

```
Counter(dataframe['a']).items()
```

Comment: This counts occurrences of entire phrases in the columns, not individual words.