# Pandas create dummy features for each string in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

Implementing the following logic for a feature engineering purpose. A simple approach is easy but wondering if there is a more efficient solution that anyone can think of. Ideas are appreciated if you don't feel like implementing the whole code!

Take this DataFrame and dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
random_animals = pd.DataFrame(
                {'description':['xdogx','xcatx','xhamsterx','xdogx'
                                ,'xhorsex','xdonkeyx','xcatx']
                })


cat_dict = {'category_a':['dog','cat']
            ,'category_b':['horse','donkey']}
```

We want to create a column/feature for each string in the dictionary AND for each category. 1 if string is contained in the `description` column 0 otherwise.

So the output for this toy example would look like:

```
  description  is_dog is_cat is_horse is_donkey is_category_a is_category_b
0       xdogx       1      0        0         0             1             0
1       xcatx       0      1        0         0             1             0    
2   xhamsterx       0      0        0         0             0             0
3       xdogx       1      0        0         0             1             0
4     xhorsex       0      0        1         0             0             1
5    xdonkeyx       0      0        0         1             0             1
6       xcatx       0      1        0         0             1             0
```

Simple approach would be iterating once for each output column required and running (for each column, just hardcoded is_dog here for simplicity)

```
random_animals['is_dog'] = random_animals['description'].str.contains('dog')*1
```

There can be an arbitrary number of strings and categories in the `cat_dict` so I am wondering if there is a way to do this otherwise.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786211/counting-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-pandas-data-frame ?

Comment: Not really, as shown in the example above, we want to be adding whole columns of 0/1, not just a count of the keywords.

Comment: There are shortcuts if you just want to test for `category_a` or `category_b`. With your problem, as stated, I do not believe you can optimise much further than `pd.Series.str.contains` (within `pandas` technology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a vectorized method. The main observation is that `random_animals.description.str.contains` when applied to a string returns a Series of indicators, one for each row of `random_animals`.

Since `random_animals.description.str.contains` is itself a vectorized function, we can apply it to the collection of animals to obtain a full indicator matrix.

Finally, we can add categories by enforcing logic between different columns. This will likely be faster than checking for string inclusion multiple times.

```
import pandas as pd
random_animals = pd.DataFrame(
                {'description':['xdogx','xcatx','xhamsterx','xdogx'
                                ,'xhorsex','xdonkeyx','xcatx']
                })


cat_dict = {'category_a':['dog', 'cat']
            ,'category_b':['horse', 'donkey']}

# create a Series containing all individual animals (without duplicates)
animals = pd.Series([animal for v in cat_dict.values()
        for animal in v])

df = pd.DataFrame(
        animals.apply(random_animals.description.str.contains).T.values,
        index  = random_animals.description,
        columns = animals).astype(int)

for cat, animals in cat_dict.items():
    df[cat] = df[animals].any(axis=1).astype(int)

             # dog  cat  horse  donkey  category_a  category_b
# description
# xdogx          1    0      0       0           1           0
# xcatx          0    1      0       0           1           0
# xhamsterx      0    0      0       0           0           0
# xdogx          1    0      0       0           1           0
# xhorsex        0    0      1       0           0           1
# xdonkeyx       0    0      0       1           0           1
# xcatx          0    1      0       0           1           0
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem. I coded what you want below, but there's problably a shorter way to do that:

```
#Creating the DataFrame with columns of zeros

names = [x[1:-1] for x in random_animals.description.unique()]
categories = list(cat_dict.keys())
columns = names + categories
df_names = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(len(random_animals)), 
columns=columns)
df = pd.concat([random_animals, df_names], axis = 1)

#Populating the Dataframe - Automating your solution

#For animal names
for i in range(len(df.columns)-1):
    df[df.columns[i+1]] = df['description'].str.contains(df.columns[i+1])*1

#For categories
if df.columns[i+1] in list(cat_dict.keys()):
    searchfor = cat_dict[df.columns[i+1]]
    df[df.columns[i+1]]= df['description'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))*1

#Finally renaming names pattern of columns from "dog" to "is_dog"...:

for column in df.columns:
 if column in names:
     column_new = "is_"+column
     df[column_new] = df[column]
     df = df.drop(column, axis =1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the pandas DataFrame class and implement a lazy column evaluation where if the derived column does not exist, implement the logic and add it to the base class columns collection.