# hive ql how to wildcard search based on keyword table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I want to return records based on a wildcard search from a table of keywords

Current Table

|  | Message |
| --- | --- |
|  | Some Message |

Keyword Table

|  | Words |
| --- | --- |
|  | SomeWord1 |
|  | SomeWord2 |

Currently I am writing a query on something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE message LIKE '%SomeWord1%' OR message LIKE '%SomeWord2%'
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this wild card search using sort of subquery

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59856125/2700344

Comment: The answer there only splits the message by individual words