# Function to check word density in a Dataframe

Tags: python, string, function, substring

Kindly help me to make a function out of code. Thanks

```
my_words = ''

for w in data3['any_column'].astype(str).values:
    my_words += '{} '.format(w.lower())
my_words = my_words.split(' ')
word_counter = {}
for w in my_words:
    if w not in word_counter:
        word_counter[w] = 1
    if w in word_counter:
        word_counter[w] += 1
word_counter_series = pd.Series(word_counter)
word_counter_series.sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me how to write a function” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Also, your follow-up questions are far too broad.  Your post distills to "do my homework in the best way possible", with requests for tutorial explanations.

Comment: A pro such as you should refrain from unnecessary exaggeration. I never asked the experts here to give tutorial explanations. I am aware that I am still learning and should not bother others. 
Anyways, Thanks for your kind response!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the Frequency of words in a pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786211/counting-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes!!! It didn't just answer my question but also helped me know many other ways I could proceed with my approach. Thanks a lot for helping me out once again!! I post my issues once I am done spending hours on those. 
Thanks!

Comment: @HenryEcker The question is just like the one I asked. I don't know why I receive discouragement from the questions I ask or even the answers I post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier alternative is using the `Counter` class.

```py
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(my_words)
```

The result will be a dictionary-like object that associates the words and how many times they appear in the list.

Comment: That's very concise and smart. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do it. here is an example:

```
from collections import Counter

def word_counter(text):
    words_list = text.split(" ")
    return Counter(words_list)
```

You can also see [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item) second answer for more details.