# Is there a way to count the frequency of words in a CSV column?

Tags: python, pandas

In my CSV I'm trying to count the frequency of words found within a column, but I don't want to look for a specific word, I wish to count the frequency of all the words. Is this possible or would I have to filter by specific words?
For example:

> Grim milestone as Australia’s aged care homes

> Damning aged care audit reveals abuse and neglect

I wish to find overlapping words within these cells without specifying words.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786211/counting-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-pandas-data-frame

Comment: Everything is possible. Are you wanting to count frequency of words in the column, or just in each row for this column? How you would go about that is different. What have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: ahh thanks Chris, that one hadn't come up before

Comment: use `value_counts()` See the same question [Counting the Frequency of words in a pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786211/counting-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: JNevill, I want to count the frequency of words across the entirety of the column, so I can create a plot that shows how often each word comes up and draw conclusion/analyse it.

Comment: That other page did help, thank you.