# creating a dictionary for big size csv data files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, chunking

I'm trying to create a dictionary file for a big size csv file that is divided into chunks to be processed, but when I'm creating the dictionary its just doing it for one chuck, and when I try to append it it passes epmty dataframe to the new df. this is the code I used

```
wdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, nrows=0,).columns[0]
skip = int(wdata.count(' ') == 0)
dic = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip, chunksize=1000):
    dic_tmp = (chunk['sentences'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().rename_axis('word').reset_index(name='freq'))


    dic.append(dic_tmp)
dic.to_csv('newwww.csv', index=False)
```

if I saved the dic_tmp one is just a dictionary for one chunk not the whole set and dic is taking alot of time to process but returns empty dataframes at the end, any error with my code ?

input csv is like

[image]

output csv is like

[image]

expected output should be

[image]

so its not adding the chunks together its just pasting the new chunk regardless what is in  the previous chunk or the csv.

Comment: I'm sorry, you should really be cautious with the python terms (e.g. "dictionary"). What you're doing here is the chunk-wise processing of a dataframe that you merge back together into a single DF. 
Could you please provide an example of the table that you're loading?

Comment: @OlegO I added some examples hope you can understand me better now

Answer (score 1):

In order to split the column into words and count the occurrences:
`df['sentences'].apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.split(" "))).sum(axis=0)`

or

`from collections import Counter
result = Counter(" ".join(df['sentences'].values.tolist()).split(" ")).items()`

both seem to be equally slow, but probably better than your approach.
Taken from here: 
[Count distinct words from a Pandas Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936957/count-distinct-words-from-a-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: non of the code is doing the required output the first one has value count in it which wont work unless I put str replace and stack in front of it to change the type from dataframe, the second one converts it  to a list. what I want is after taking each chunk check the previous chunk if the word is there increase the frequency of the word if its new append it to the end of the file and go to the next chunk

Comment: @programmingfreak I checked the first method myself, and it does create a list of available words with the count (unsorted, though, but this is irrelevant, I guess), i.e. exactly what you have in "expected output should be". From your explanation I really don't understand what your issue with it is.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems that I see are

1. Why read the csv file twice? 
   First time here `wdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, nrows=0,).columns[0]` and second time in the `for` loop.
2. If you aren't using the combined data frame further. I think it is better to write the chunks to csv file in append mode like shown below

```py
for chunk in pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip, chunksize=1000):
    dic_tmp = (chunk['sentences'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().rename_axis('word').reset_index(name='freq'))
    dic_tmp.to_csv('newwww.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

Comment: I'm reading it twice first it checks if it has a header if it has it will remove it then name the header sentences because its user based input so Im not assuming that the user input will be a fixed header

Comment: Ok. Understood. Try the optimization in the second point. May be it helps

Comment: it gives wrong output it doesnt unfortunately it doesnt add up to a word if its already available in the previous chunks it will just print it again as a new one.

Comment: I have modified the question if you can help more @abhilb